# Elemento HTML se reajusta com o resize da tela

Tags: html, css, svg

Possuo o seguinte código.

```js
var logo = document.getElementById("svgLogo");
var area1 = document.getElementById("area1");
var area2 = document.getElementById("area2");
var area3 = document.getElementById("area3");
var area4 = document.getElementById("area4");

area1.addEventListener('click', function(){
 console.log("ÁREA 1");
 area1.classList.add("animationLogin1");
 area2.classList.add("animationLogin2");
 area3.classList.add("animationLogin3");
 area4.classList.add("animationLogin4");


 var timer = setInterval(hidden,3990);
 stars1.classList.add("transition");
 stars2.classList.add("transition");
 stars3.classList.add("transition");
});

area2.addEventListener('click', function(){
 console.log("ÁREA 2");
 area1.classList.add("animationLogin1");
 area2.classList.add("animationLogin2");
 area3.classList.add("animationLogin3");
 area4.classList.add("animationLogin4");


 var timer = setInterval(hidden,3990);
 stars1.classList.add("transition");
 stars2.classList.add("transition");
 stars3.classList.add("transition");
});

area3.addEventListener('click', function(){
 console.log("ÁREA 3");
 area1.classList.add("animationLogin1");
 area2.classList.add("animationLogin2");
 area3.classList.add("animationLogin3");
 area4.classList.add("animationLogin4");


 var timer = setInterval(hidden,3990);
 stars1.classList.add("transition");
 stars2.classList.add("transition");
 stars3.classList.add("transition");
});

area4.addEventListener('click', function(){
 console.log("ÁREA 4");
 area1.classList.add("animationLogin1");
 area2.classList.add("animationLogin2");
 area3.classList.add("animationLogin3");
 area4.classList.add("animationLogin4");


 var timer = setInterval(hidden,3990);
 stars1.classList.add("transition");
 stars2.classList.add("transition");
 stars3.classList.add("transition");
});

function hidden(){
 logo.style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
#svgLogo{
  position: absolute;
  height: 1000px;
  width: 1000px;
  top: calc(35% - 500px);
  left: calc(50% - 500px);
}

#area1{
  position:absolute;
  /*height:200%;*/
  margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;
  stroke: white;
  stroke-width: 0.2;
  fill: #4285F4;

}

#area2{
  position:absolute;
  /*height:200%;*/
  margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;
  stroke: white;
  stroke-width: 0.15;
  fill: #34A853;

}

#area3{
  position:absolute;
  /*height:200%;*/
  margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;
  stroke: white;
  stroke-width: 0.15;
  fill: #FBBC05;

}

#area4{
  position:absolute;
  /*height:200%;*/
  margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;
  stroke: white;
  stroke-width: 0.15;
  fill: #EA4335;

}     

.animationLogin1{
  -webkit-animation-name: globalRotate;  
  /* Center=cx/viewBox=20.5/41=50% */
  -webkit-transform-origin:  50% 50%; 
  -webkit-animation-duration: 4s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0s;
  z-index:1;
} 

.animationLogin2{
  -webkit-animation-name: globalRotate; 
  /* Center=cx/viewBox=20.5/41=50% */
  -webkit-transform-origin:  50% 50%; 
  -webkit-animation-duration: 4s; 
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.5s;
  z-index:1;
} 

.animationLogin3{
  -webkit-animation-name: globalRotate;  
  /* Center=cx/viewBox=20.5/41=50% */
  -webkit-transform-origin:  50% 50%; 
  -webkit-animation-duration: 4s; 
  -webkit-animation-delay: 1s;
  z-index:1;
} 

.animationLogin4{
  -webkit-animation-name: globalRotate;
  /* Center=cx/viewBox=20.5/41=50% */
  -webkit-transform-origin:  50% 50%; 
  -webkit-animation-duration: 4s; 
  -webkit-animation-delay: 1.5s;
  z-index:1;   
} 

@keyframes globalRotate {
0%   {-webkit-transform: translate(0px,0px) rotate(0deg) scale(1,1); opacity:1}
/*50% {-webkit-transform: translate(0px,0px) rotate(180deg) scale(1,1);opacity:1}*/
100% {-webkit-transform: translate(0px,0px) rotate(1800deg) scale(0.2,0.2);opacity:0}
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en' class=''>
 <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="SpaceX.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Baner.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ButtonMenu.css">

 </head>

 <body>
  
   <svg id="svgLogo" viewBox="0 0 41 41">

          <path id="area1"
             d="M21.7,27.35 21.6,22.3Q19.25,24.8 16.9,27.3Q15.85,25.75 14.8,24.2Q16.25,20.85 17.7,17.5Q17.75,15.55         17.8,13.6Q18.75,14.35 19.7,15.1Q21,15.5 22.6,16.4Q27.85,21.8 21.7,27.35" stroke-linecap="round"/>
             
            <path id="area2"
             d="M17,30.4Q19.45,29.05 21.7,27.35Q27.85,21.8 22.6,16.4Q23.65,16.9 24.75,17.9Q30.1,21.95 24.7,30.15Q20.85,31.7       17,30.4" stroke-linecap="round"/>
             
             <path id="area3"
             d="M24.7,30.15Q30.1,21.95 24.75,17.9Q28.05,20.25 28.3,24.95Q28.3,26.2 27.85,28Q26.35,29.5 24.7,30.15" stroke-      linecap="round" />

             <path id="area4"
             d="M21.7,27.35 21.6,22.3Q19.25,24.8 16.9,27.3Q15.85,25.75 14.8,24.2Q16.25,20.85 17.7,17.5Q17.75,15.55 17.8,13.6Q18.75,14.35 19.7,15.1Q21,15.5 22.6,16.4Q23.65,16.9 24.75,17.9Q28.05,20.25 28.3,24.95Q28.3,26.2 27.85,28Q29.1,26.8 29.85,25.25Q30.65,23.75 30.9,22.05Q31.15,20.35 30.85,18.65Q30.55,16.95 29.7,15.5Q28.95,13.95 27.65,12.8Q26.4,11.6 24.85,10.95Q23.3,10.2 21.6,10.05Q19.9,9.85 18.2,10.25Q16.55,10.6 15.1,11.5Q13.6,12.35 12.5,13.7Q11.35,15 10.75,16.6Q10.1,18.15 10,19.85Q9.9,21.6 10.35,23.25Q10.8,24.9 11.75,26.3Q12.65,27.75 14.05,28.8Q15.4,29.85 17,30.4Q19.45,29.05 21.7,27.35" stroke-linecap="round" />
        </svg>

 </body>
</html>
```

estou tentando fazer com que a animação se reajuste ao tamanho da tela

estou tentando usar **display: flex**

Comment: Cara não ficou claro o que vc quer fazer... A sua ideia é centralizar a logo no centro da tela na horizontal e vertical é isso?

Comment: @hugocsl, desculpe se não ficou claro.

Estou querendo fazer com que minha logo reajuste de tamanho de acordo com o resize da tela, permanecendo sempre no centro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cara tem alguns detalhes, primeiro que para alinhar o elemento no centro da tela a forma como vc fez com `position:absolute` e `transforma:translate` não vai dar certo. Como vc falou que está usando flex, sugiro que use propriedades do `flex` como `justify-content` e `align-itens`. Além disso, coloque seu SVG dentro de um `container`. que ocupe toda a largura/altura da tela, e com o `flex` vc alinha o SVG no centro.

Para deixar o SVG mais responsivo declare a largura/altura em % ou VW/VH dependendo. Assim ele vai ficar mais responsivo como na imagem. Eu usei um *hakezinho* usando `transform:scale()` só para ajustar o `path` dentro do `viewbox` de forma que não ficasse "espaço sobrando" no canvas do SVG, isso vai facilitar pra vc controlar o tamanho do SVG no total

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

***OBS***: Seu código JavaScript tem um erro, mas não é minha especialidade então vou deixar para vc resolver depois, já que não está no escopo da pergunta.

Segue código da imagem acima:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
    
    #svgLogo{
  /* position: absolute; */
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  /* top: calc(35% - 500px); */
  /* left: calc(50% - 500px); */
}

#area1{
  position:absolute;
  /*height:200%;*/
  margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;
  stroke: white;
  stroke-width: 0.2;
  fill: #4285F4;
   transform-origin: center;

}

#area2{
  position:absolute;
  /*height:200%;*/
  margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;
  stroke: white;
  stroke-width: 0.15;
  fill: #34A853;
   transform-origin: center;

}

#area3{
  position:absolute;
  /*height:200%;*/
  margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;
  stroke: white;
  stroke-width: 0.15;
  fill: #FBBC05;
   transform-origin: center;

}

#area4{
  position:absolute;
  /*height:200%;*/
  margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;
  stroke: white;
  stroke-width: 0.15;
  fill: #EA4335;
   transform-origin: center;

}     

.animationLogin1{
  -webkit-animation-name: globalRotate;  
  /* Center=cx/viewBox=20.5/41=50% */
  -webkit-transform-origin:  50% 50%; 
  -webkit-animation-duration: 4s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0s;
  z-index:1;
} 

.animationLogin2{
  -webkit-animation-name: globalRotate; 
  /* Center=cx/viewBox=20.5/41=50% */
  -webkit-transform-origin:  50% 50%; 
  -webkit-animation-duration: 4s; 
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.5s;
  z-index:1;
} 

.animationLogin3{
  -webkit-animation-name: globalRotate;  
  /* Center=cx/viewBox=20.5/41=50% */
  -webkit-transform-origin:  50% 50%; 
  -webkit-animation-duration: 4s; 
  -webkit-animation-delay: 1s;
  z-index:1;
} 

.animationLogin4{
  -webkit-animation-name: globalRotate;
  /* Center=cx/viewBox=20.5/41=50% */
  -webkit-transform-origin:  50% 50%; 
  -webkit-animation-duration: 4s; 
  -webkit-animation-delay: 1.5s;
  z-index:1;   
} 

@keyframes globalRotate {
0%   {-webkit-transform: translate(0px,0px) rotate(0deg) scale(1,1); opacity:1; transform-origin: center}
/*50% {-webkit-transform: translate(0px,0px) rotate(180deg) scale(1,1);opacity:1}*/
100% {-webkit-transform: translate(0px,0px) rotate(1800deg) scale(0.2,0.2);opacity:0; transform-origin: center}
}  

html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#svgLogo path {
    transform: scale(1.9);
}

.container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
 
<div class="container">
        <svg id="svgLogo" viewBox="0 0 41 41">
    
            <path id="area1"
            d="M21.7,27.35 21.6,22.3Q19.25,24.8 16.9,27.3Q15.85,25.75 14.8,24.2Q16.25,20.85 17.7,17.5Q17.75,15.55         17.8,13.6Q18.75,14.35 19.7,15.1Q21,15.5 22.6,16.4Q27.85,21.8 21.7,27.35" stroke-linecap="round"/>
            
           <path id="area2"
            d="M17,30.4Q19.45,29.05 21.7,27.35Q27.85,21.8 22.6,16.4Q23.65,16.9 24.75,17.9Q30.1,21.95 24.7,30.15Q20.85,31.7       17,30.4" stroke-linecap="round"/>
            
            <path id="area3"
            d="M24.7,30.15Q30.1,21.95 24.75,17.9Q28.05,20.25 28.3,24.95Q28.3,26.2 27.85,28Q26.35,29.5 24.7,30.15" stroke-      linecap="round" />
    
            <path id="area4"
            d="M21.7,27.35 21.6,22.3Q19.25,24.8 16.9,27.3Q15.85,25.75 14.8,24.2Q16.25,20.85 17.7,17.5Q17.75,15.55 17.8,13.6Q18.75,14.35 19.7,15.1Q21,15.5 22.6,16.4Q23.65,16.9 24.75,17.9Q28.05,20.25 28.3,24.95Q28.3,26.2 27.85,28Q29.1,26.8 29.85,25.25Q30.65,23.75 30.9,22.05Q31.15,20.35 30.85,18.65Q30.55,16.95 29.7,15.5Q28.95,13.95 27.65,12.8Q26.4,11.6 24.85,10.95Q23.3,10.2 21.6,10.05Q19.9,9.85 18.2,10.25Q16.55,10.6 15.1,11.5Q13.6,12.35 12.5,13.7Q11.35,15 10.75,16.6Q10.1,18.15 10,19.85Q9.9,21.6 10.35,23.25Q10.8,24.9 11.75,26.3Q12.65,27.75 14.05,28.8Q15.4,29.85 17,30.4Q19.45,29.05 21.7,27.35" stroke-linecap="round" />
          </svg>
</div>
    
<script>
    var logo = document.getElementById("svgLogo");
var area1 = document.getElementById("area1");
var area2 = document.getElementById("area2");
var area3 = document.getElementById("area3");
var area4 = document.getElementById("area4");

area1.addEventListener('click', function(){
 console.log("ÁREA 1");
 area1.classList.add("animationLogin1");
 area2.classList.add("animationLogin2");
 area3.classList.add("animationLogin3");
 area4.classList.add("animationLogin4");


 var timer = setInterval(hidden,3990);
 stars1.classList.add("transition");
 stars2.classList.add("transition");
 stars3.classList.add("transition");
});

area2.addEventListener('click', function(){
 console.log("ÁREA 2");
 area1.classList.add("animationLogin1");
 area2.classList.add("animationLogin2");
 area3.classList.add("animationLogin3");
 area4.classList.add("animationLogin4");


 var timer = setInterval(hidden,3990);
 stars1.classList.add("transition");
 stars2.classList.add("transition");
 stars3.classList.add("transition");
});

area3.addEventListener('click', function(){
 console.log("ÁREA 3");
 area1.classList.add("animationLogin1");
 area2.classList.add("animationLogin2");
 area3.classList.add("animationLogin3");
 area4.classList.add("animationLogin4");


 var timer = setInterval(hidden,3990);
 stars1.classList.add("transition");
 stars2.classList.add("transition");
 stars3.classList.add("transition");
});

area4.addEventListener('click', function(){
 console.log("ÁREA 4");
 area1.classList.add("animationLogin1");
 area2.classList.add("animationLogin2");
 area3.classList.add("animationLogin3");
 area4.classList.add("animationLogin4");


 var timer = setInterval(hidden,3990);
 stars1.classList.add("transition");
 stars2.classList.add("transition");
 stars3.classList.add("transition");
});

function hidden(){
 logo.style.display = "none";
}

</script>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Muito abrigado por todas as dicas, me ajudou bastante

Comment: Sem problemas amigo que bom que ajudou ai. Como vc tb usou Scale na amimação, pode ser que vc tenha que fazer um ajuste fino para ficar legal, mudando um pouco os valores do scale no keyframes, mas acredito que a partir desse código vc já vai conseguir ajustar conforme deseja. Sucesso

Comment: Sim sim, só mais uma dúvida, todo elemento que eu queira que tenha esse comportamento posso colocar no mesmo container ou crio um para cada elemento ?

Comment: @GabrielSilva cara o SVG ocupa um "espaço" na tela, como qq elemento, tipo uma imagem ou div. Para ele "flutuar" na tela vc teria que usar position:absolute no SVG, assim vc consegue ir colocando um elemento encima do outro e controlando com z-index que fica por cima etc. Se vc tiver alguma dúvida quanto a isso mais precisamente monta uma nova pergunta com um exemplo do que está tentando fazer, explique com detalhes e coloque o código e imagem etc. Ai eu ou outro usuário pode te ajudar mais precisamente